# Object Variable error on an If statement when no value is required

Tags: excel, vba, loops, if-statement

I have an issue with the following code

```
TestCheck:

    Dim Comm as Range
    Dim TestComment as Range


    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Set TestComment = Intersect(Application.ActiveSheet.Range("I:I"), Target)
    On Error GoTo Cancellation

    If TestComment = "" Then

    Else
        For Each Comm In TestComment
            If Not VBA.IsEmpty(Comm.Value) Then
                Comm.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
                Comm.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"

                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next
    End If
```

It keeps bringing up the error

> 'Object variable or with block variable not set'

on the If statement

```
If TestComment = "" Then
```

I get that it equals nothings so it freaks out, but I don't mind that it equals nothing, in fact in that case id rather it did nothing if it equals nothing instead of throwing an error. On Error GoTo doesn't seem to work either.

Comment: `TestComment` is an object. So, please replace `If TestComment = "" Then` with `If TestComment is nothing Then`... Or directly `If Not TestComment Is Nothing Then` and do what you need doing...

Comment: Ahh of course, how dumb of me! Thank you

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If Target is not in column `I`, the function `Intersect` will return `Nothing`, so `TestComment` is set to `Nothing`.
You cannot check the value of `Nothing`, you will need to check if it is set to something, you can use `is Nothing` for that.

I assume your code is part of a event routine. Note that you shouldn't set
`EnableEvents` to True while the code is still working - put it to the end of your code (behind label `Cancellation`) to ensure that it is executed even if an error occurs.

```
Application.EnableEvents = False
On Error GoTo Cancellation
Dim testComment As Range, comm As Range
Set testComment = Intersect(Range("I:I"), Target)

If Not testComment Is Nothing Then
    For Each comm In testComment
        If Not IsEmpty(comm.Value) Then
            comm.Offset(0, 1).Value = Date
            comm.Offset(0, 1).NumberFormat = "dd/mm/yyyy"
        End If
    Next
End If
Cancellation:
Application.EnableEvents = True
```